# Regex to match markdown image pattern with the given filename

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace a markdown image pattern with the given filename in the textarea with an empty string.

So the pattern is `![alt](http://somehost/uploads/filename.jpg)`

This is the code I have now:

```
var content = target.val();
var fileName = someDynamicValue;

var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape('![') + '.*' + RegExp.escape(']') + RegExp.escape('(') + '.*' + RegExp.escape(fileName) + RegExp.escape(')'), 'i');
var found = regex.exec(content);

var newContent = content.replace(regex, "");
target.val(newContent);

RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
};
```

For example `var fileName = filename.jpg`. Then I need to match `![alt](http://somehost/uploads/filename.jpg)` and replace it with an empty string.

Everything works great if the `content` includes one image. But if there are more then one, for example:

> Some text `![alt](http://somehost/uploads/filename.jpg)` some text `![alt2](http://somehost/uploads/filename2.jpg)` more text.

then `var found` includes `![alt](http://somehost/uploads/filename.jpg)![alt2](http://somehost/uploads/filename2.jpg)`, but I need to match only `![alt](http://somehost/uploads/filename.jpg)`.

What regex I need in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you are trying to put the strings together but
`'.*'` is greedily matching up to the last filename.
So, it should probably be `'.*?'`.

However, if the filenames are different then it shouldn't have matched.
Another thing is you should in general stop it from running past the next `[alt]` with
something like `'[^\[\]]*'`

**Edit:**

RegExp.escape('![') + `'.*'` + RegExp.escape(']') + RegExp.escape('(') + '.*' + RegExp.escape(fileName) + RegExp.escape(')'), 'i');

is the culprit.

Try

`RegExp.escape('![') + '[^\]]*' + RegExp.escape(']') + RegExp.escape('(') + '[^\[\]]*?' + RegExp.escape(fileName) + RegExp.escape(')'), 'i');`

Comment: Also, I'm not an expert on JS escaping.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example of your regex wihout this escape functions? I will remake then by myself ;)

Comment: Well I tried your code, made some escapes and it worked! Thank you again. My complete code is: `var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape('![') + '[^'+ RegExp.escape(']') + ']*' + RegExp.escape(']') + RegExp.escape('(') + '[^' + RegExp.escape('[]') + ']*?' + RegExp.escape(fileName) + RegExp.escape(')'), 'i');`

Answer (score 2):

Use non-greedy quantifiers will do:

`!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)`

You can check it out online: https://regex101.com/r/kfi8qI