# Capture markdown image syntax on a single line

Tags: regex

I'm using this regular expression

`\!\[.*\]\[(.*)\]`

to capture image syntax tags for markdown. However, whenever I encounter a paragraph with more than 1 markdown image syntax on it, regex only considers it only as one image syntax.

Comment: `*` is *greedy*, use `.*?` instead, or `\[([^\]*)]`. Also note that since the first `[` was quoted, no need to quote the closing one.

Comment: Or you can consult some existing implementation. For example here is [the one used by SO](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Converter.js): `/(\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*)\]\([ \t]*()<?((?:\([^)]*\)|[^()\s])*?)>?[ \t]*((['"])(.*?)\6[ \t]*)?\))/g` (The `<?` and `>?` are probably leftover from processing HTML? You can remove them)

Comment: It works like charm @MarounMaroun ! Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match markdown image pattern with the given filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128238/regex-to-match-markdown-image-pattern-with-the-given-filename)

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
\!\[[^\]]*\]\[([^\]]*)\]
```

or

```
\!\[.*?\]\[(.*?)\]
```

Comment: It will work, just not fits to the syntax: the second `[]` should be `()`